# Unity Editor: Get Mouse coordinates on left click on Scene Editor

Tags: unity, c#

I need a simple script which does the following:

When I left-click somewhere in the Editor-Scene:

(doesnt matter if there is an object under the cursor- or not)

Do NOT deselect the current selection in the Inspector. 
Do not select the object under the cursor.
and

### Just print the mouse X and Z interception with the Y-Plane in the Debug.Log();

i stumbled on many solutions but somehow i couldnt get this to work.

i tried:

HandleUtility.AddDefaultControl(GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive));

and

Tools.current = Tool.None;

both seem to do nothing ..... X.x

EDIT:

Happens that 
"HandleUtility.AddDefaultControl(GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive));"
needs to be inside:
public void OnSceneGUI()
and called every frame - to "block" the mouse clicks on the editor.
i thought it toggles it off.

still the problem of the mouse coordinates persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my little problem. This is the solution I came up with:

```
Ray ray;
RaycastHit hit;

ray = Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Event.current.mousePosition.x, SceneView.currentDrawingSceneView.camera.pixelHeight - Event.current.mousePosition.y));

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
    x1 = Input.mousePosition.x;
    y1 = Input.mousePosition.y;
    z1 = Input.mousePosition.z;
    x2 = hit.point.x;
    y2 = 0;
    z2 = hit.point.z;
}
```

This script gets the mouse coordinates on the y-plane if there is a collider on the y-plane.

x2,x2,z2 are the result coordinates.

Comment: For custom editor code you should use `HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay()` instead of `ScreenPointToRay()`.